How to use vite-plugin-rewrite-all with Quasar (Vue 3)? (or enable periods in path another way)
When using quasar+vite in vueRouterMode: 'history' mode with paths matching thing/:id where the id has a period/dot, a 404 is returned. This is documented in a few different places:

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2415
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4344
Handling dot in vue-router params using vue 3

Everyone seems to recommend using vite-plugin-rewrite-all, but the specified usage is:
// vite.config.js
import pluginRewriteAll from 'vite-plugin-rewrite-all';

export default {
  plugins: [pluginRewriteAll()]
}

I've read the docs, but I'm having trouble getting this plugin to work (or find any other solution to the period/dot issue) using quasar.config.js. I don't appear to be able to import or require this ES Module in quasar.config.js
# Using:
# import pluginRewriteAll from 'vite-plugin-rewrite-all'

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

# Using:
# const pluginRewriteAll = require('vite-plugin-rewrite-all')

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ./node_modules/vite-plugin-rewrite-all/dist/index.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of ./node_modules/vite-plugin-rewrite-all/dist/index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules. code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'

Can anyone assist?

This is a CJS vs ESM issue. I guess that besides forking this project and updating it yourself there is not much too do. But there might be another package for that kind of problem. Btw I just realized that . is a valid character for an URL. Confirmation: https://github.com/ivesia/vite-plugin-rewrite-all/issues/7

Looks like Vite 5 solves this issue because it's baked in. Might give it a try?

The current GA release of @quasar/app-vite is stuck on Vite v2. @quasar/app-vite v2 is currently in beta, but supports Vite 5, which will be nice. Vite 5 also requires node 18, which I'll have to upgrade to first.

Oh wow quite old version for sure. And yes a node upgrade would be nice considering the fact that the LTS is v20.

I finally got this working by configuring my quasar.config.js as follows:
module.exports = configure(async function(/* ctx */) {
  const pluginRewriteAll = await import('vite-plugin-rewrite-all')
  return {
    build: {
      vitePlugins: [
        pluginRewriteAll.default()
      ]
    }
  }
})

I had to make the export function async, then was able to await the import. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it seems to work.
It looks as if Vite 5 fixes this natively, so I'm really looking forward to a @quasar/app-vite v2 GA release, which supports it.
Update:
Turns out vite-plugin-rewrite-all v1.0.2 has an issue loading as an ESM. If you pin to v1.0.1, the following works too:
const pluginRewriteAll = require('vite-plugin-rewrite-all')
module.exports = configure(function(/* ctx */) {
  return {
    build: {
      vitePlugins: [
        pluginRewriteAll.default()
      ]
    }
  }
})

This feels a little less hacky.

This is definitely just gaftape to make it work. You can load it but lose lots of benefits of an (native) ESM module.
